# Desabilitar a opção "sql-mode=only_full_group_by"

Tags: mysql

Instalei o mysql no meu note e estou usando o Linux Mint 18.2. Quando executo a query:

```
SELECT *,SUM(ValorTotalProdutos) AS ValorTotal, SUM(QtdProdutos) AS QtdFinal FROM tabela WHERE SESSIONID = '77c2c1de02e94581a459ed2d4fa76370' AND StatusCompras = 'A'
```

Aparece o erro:

```
#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'banco.tabela.IDCarrinho'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Abri o arquivo **my.cnf**

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

E inclui no final do arquivo:

```
sql-mode=""
```

Reiniciei o mysql:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

E deu erro. Então apaguei o comando acima e incluí outra linha:

```
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Reiniciei e o mesmo erro apareceu. O erro que apareceu em ambos é:

```
sudo service mysql restart
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Como faço para desabilitar o sql-mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As opções para alterar o SQL MODE são estas:

Usando isto na linha de comando ao iniciar o servidor:

```
--sql-mode="modes"
```

Ou no arquivo de configuração:

```
sql-mode="modes"
```

Em _runtime:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';
```

É importante se certificar de todas as opções, pois você pode ter alguma de maior prioridade anulando a que alterou manualmente (ou ter alterado num arquivo, e a opção sendo setada em outro).

Por exemplo, mesmo que você especifique a opção no `my.cnf` ou equivalente, se o script que inicializa o servidor fizer a opção de linha de comando, esta prevalecerá.

Vale notar que o *default* desta opção foi alterado na versão 5.7.5 do MySQL.

Ainda, lembre-se de alterar somente o modo que está afetando seu uso, mantendo as outras opções da maneira que se encontram para evitar efeitos colaterais.

Agora, se possível, revise a lógica da *query*, eventualmente possa ser uma solução mais definitiva e portátil para o problema.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: Obrigado Bacco.

Comment: @Fox.11 conseguiu com alguma das opções? Eu sugiro você repensar na query para seu script ficar portátil em outros servidores, a não ser que tenha certeza de que vai sempre ter controle sobre o ambiente

Comment: Olá Bacco. Opcionei em colocar Group By no final da query. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode realizar configurações do banco em tempo de execução no PHP.
É mais prático, pois caso você precise trocar para outro servidor não precisará refazer as configurações novamente.

Se estiver usando PDO execute essa query logo após instanciar o objeto PDO:

$Pdo->exec("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));");

Veja o exemplo:

```
<?php
namespace lib;
class Dao
{
    private static $Dao;
    private static $Pdo;

    final private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            self::$Pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . CONEXAO['host'] . ";dbname=" . CONEXAO['database'], CONEXAO['user'], CONEXAO['password']);
            self::$Pdo->exec("SET TIME_ZONE = '-03:00'");
            self::$Pdo->exec("set names " . APP_CHARSET);
            self::$Pdo->exec("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));");
            self::$Pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$Pdo->query("SET group_concat_max_len = " . GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN);
        } catch (\PDOException $ex) {
            throw new SystemExceptions($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    //...

}
```